# Multiple classes with similar implementation, used with different corresponding classes?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, code-duplication, factory-method

In a C# project, I'm stuck in a situation where I'm writing a lot of code to implement very similar functionality. I feel like I should be able to refactor this somehow, but I'm not sure what to do.

In short, I have a list of classes `AClass`, `BClass`, etc. that inherit from a base class. Each class can accept a list of conditions unique to that class. For example, `AClass` can accept conditions of type `ACondition`, and `BClass` can accept conditions of type `BCondition`. Each condition class is an abstract class in the factory model that can accept nested conditions of a common set of derived classes, "AndCondition", "OrCondition", "NotCondition", so that the usage is something like the below example.

```
AClass foo = new AClass();
foo.SetConditions(ACondition.And(ACondition.Factory1(),
    ACondition.Not(ACondition.Factory2())));
```

Of course, I could write the same kind of thing for `BClass`, with `BCondition` having different factories. My thought was to create a generic abstract class and inherit from it.

```
public abstract Condition<T>
{
    public static Condition<T> And(Condition<T> c1, Condition<T> c2)
    {
        // Returns an AndCondition derived from Condition<T>.
    }

    // Other common implementation.
}

public abstract ACondition : Condition<AClass>
{
    public static ACondition Factory1()
    {
        // Returns some class derived from ACondition.
    }

    // Other factory implementations.
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this. First, at present, I'm not using `T` for anything except to distinguish between different instances of this class. This is necessary to prevent accidental (or intentional) use of a `BCondition` where an `ACondition` is expected. However, it doesn't prevent someone from creating another class derived from `Condition<AClass>` and using it where it's not expected. In other words, someone can do the following:

```
public class MyACondition : Condition<AClass>
{
    public MyACondition()
    {
        // Initialize a new instance of MyACondition.
    }
}
```

And then later inject it unwantedly like so:

```
AClass foo = new AClass();
foo.SetConditions(ACondition.Not(new MyACondition()));
```

I also tried making T the return type; e.g. changing `Condition<T> And(Condition<T> c1, Condition<T> c2)` to `T And(T c1, T c2)`, but that forces me to inherit from `T`, which isn't allowed. So, for now, I have to write separate `And`, `Or`, and `Not` factories for each of my Condition classes. It seems like there should be a better way, but I'm stumped.

Comment: How about make interface for `AClass`, e.g. `ICanOnlyBeUsedByA` and then use `public static Condition<T> And(Condition<T> c1, Condition<T> c2) where T : ICanONlyBeUsedByA`. Do this for the rest of classes too. I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly.

Comment: But there is nothing to stop another class from implementing `ICanOnlyBeUsedByA` and also deriving from `Condition<AClass>`. The problem is that I want to only accept `ACondition` parameters for And, Or, Not, etc. where the `ACondition` may be compound. If that were it, it would be simple. But because I also need (potentially compound) `BCondition`s and `CCondition`s, it makes everything more complicated.

Comment: Maybe I'm worrying too much about users supplying invalid values and should just throw an exception if the data is invalid. Still, as much as possible, I want to provide strongly-typed parameters.

Comment: Will some generic constraint like below help you?.... `public static ACondition Not<T> (T factory) where T: ACondition`

Comment: Only if I have to implement `Not<T>` on the `ACondition` level. I'd rather implement it on the `Condition<T>` level, but that would require me to inherit from the upper level generic. E.g. `public abstract class Condition<T>`...`public static Condition<T> Not<U> (U factory) where U: T`. I'm thinking to try a different approach where `ACondition`, `BCondition`, etc., are wrapper classes for a `Conditional` class that implements all of the `And`, `Or`, and `Not` behavior.